# Schengen Visa Previously collected fingerprints

Tags: schengen-visas

I am applying for Schengen visa and form requires me to mention details of fingerprints collected previously.
I have travelled on multiple occasions and I believe fingerprints might have been collected but I am not sure.

What would be the proper response to this question given that i am not sure.

Comment: If you don't remember,write that. Otherwise state probably when the last visa was issued.

Comment: @MarkJohnson It is possible to find out if fingerprints were taken, I have updated answer below.

Answer (score 4):

In order to check if finger prints were collected in previous applications of Schengen visa then see the remarks section on visa stamp, if it mentions "VIS" then fingerprints were collected.

More details can be checked at this [link](https://btwvisas.com/schengen-visa/schengen-visa-sticker#:%7E:text=The%20most%20common%20remarks%20are,been%20recorded%20in%20the%20past.)